# Android Studio project can't resolve ActionBarSherlock imports

Tags: actionbarsherlock, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android Studio project which has a dependency on ActionBarSherlock set in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile project(':Core')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

The project builds successfully on the command line with `gradle assemble assembleDebug` and also builds and runs just fine from the IDE when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. When I view some of the Sherlock-related source files in the IDE, though, the file is full of red error notifications, starting with this line:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockPreferenceActivity;
```

The tooltip that pops up says

> Cannot resolve symbol 'SherlockPreferenceActivity'

and none of the context-sensitive stuff such as auto-completion is available.

I had tried the *File > Invalidate Caches/Restart > Invalidate and Restart* menu option, which doesn't seem to have cured the problem. How can I get Android Studio to correctly resolve this import?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First sync your project with gradle and check if it gives some error, if it worked fine go back and try importing something from actionbarsherlock library in any of your class.

If above step doesn't help. Check once Your_Project/your_module/build/exploded-bundles/ComActionbarsherlock.../classes.jar exists or not.

Then go for this :

Clean your project from `Build > Clean Project`, sync your project with gradle than check this for reference.

[Import Google Play Services library in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081598/import-google-play-services-library-in-android-studio/21086904#21086904)

Or Follow the steps :

- Exit Android Studio
- Delete all the .iml files and files inside .idea folder from your project
- Relaunch Android Studio and wait till the project synced completely with gradle

This is bug in Android Studio 0.4.2 and fixed for Android Studio 0.4.3 release.