# android studio editor bug (cannot result symbol)

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Why sometimes android studio does not see external library even after adding dependencies in build.gradle? Dependecies are right, project synchronized with Gradle files.
P.S. Gradle complete building task  succesfully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235851/android-studio-project-cant-resolve-actionbarsherlock-imports/21236808#21236808

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I do exactly what written in that answer. So now I will wait for 0.4.3.

Comment: is your problem got resolved ?

Comment: Yes, after deleting .idea and .iml and relaunching android studio project building complete succesfully. But I don't like that I every time should delete files, hope,  this problem would be fixed in 0.4.3

Comment: ya it is already fixed for next release.