# ActionBarActivity cannot resolve a symbol

Tags: android, android-studio

In my android Studio, Compiler is not able to locate `ActionBarActivity`. Because of it, I am getting many errors. The compiler is not able to import the `ActionBarActivity` and `ActionBar` class. 
These are the lines where compiler is throwing error:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
```

I tried to search on stackoverflow before asking a question. The answer i got is for the eclipse which is to add the library. I tried doing it in Android Studio, but didn't get anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235851/android-studio-project-cant-resolve-actionbarsherlock-imports/21236808#21236808

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Follow the steps mentioned for using support ActionBar in Android Studio(0.4.2) :**

Download the Android Support Repository from Android SDK Manager, SDK Manager icon will be available on Android Studio tool bar (or `Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager`).

[image]

After download you will find your Support repository here

```
$SDK_DIR\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7
```

Open your main module's **build.gradle** file and add following dependency for using action bar in lower API level

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

Sync your project with gradle using the tiny Gradle icon available in toolbar  (or `Tools -> Android -> Sync Project With Gradle Files`).

There is some issue going on with Android Studio 0.4.2 so check this as well if you face any issue while importing classes in code.

[Import Google Play Services library in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081598/import-google-play-services-library-in-android-studio/21086904#21086904)

If Required follow the steps as well :

- Exit Android Studio
- Delete all the .iml files and files inside .idea folder from your
  project
- Relaunch Android Studio and wait till the project synced completely
  with gradle. If it shows an error in Event Log with import option click on Import Project.

This is bug in Android Studio 0.4.2 and fixed for Android Studio 0.4.3 release.

Comment: Thanks pyus13 for your help. Its working now with the sol you provided.

Comment: Thanks last part of your answer solved my problem (If Required follow the steps as well...)

Comment: great enjoy developing with Android Studio :)

Comment: This issue persists still in AS 0.6.1; had to do the 'If Required' section as well to resolve my errors

Comment: Quite strange for me, the issue was fixed long back.

Comment: Where can I find build.gradle?

Comment: Every Android Studio project has .iml files in root of evey module and Root project directory as well.

Comment: Very thorough! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the same error occurs in ADT/Eclipse

Add [Action Bar Sherlock library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) in your project.

Now, to remove the **"import The import android.support.v7 cannot be resolved"** error
download a jar file named as **[android-support-v7-appcompat.jar](https://github.com/koush/android-support-v7-appcompat/raw/master/libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar)** and add it in your project **lib** folder.

This will surely removes your both errors.

Comment: It's best to use library projects instead of jars.  Proguard will only clean up resources from library projects, not jars.

Answer (score 1):

Probaly you are getting the error on an Activity. Assuming as so, where you have

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

you need to replace by

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

you also need to change the import from

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

to

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

and finally, you need to add the dependency to the `build.gradle` file

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:xxx.0.+'
```

where xxx is the `compileSdkVersion` version of your App., up to 28.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the path to the project there is no foldername having whitespace. While creating a project the specified path folders must not contain any space in their naming.