# android.support library failing to import

Tags: android-studio

I've read a few of the fixes for this, but none seem to be working properly, this is my build.gradle (which I already had to fix a bunch of).

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}
```

and my wrapper settings:

```
#Mon Jan 27 15:30:40 CST 2014
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip
```

It should be working since this was working before I updated to v0.4.4 but now I can't seem to get the v4 libraries to import, even the ones android studio adds in by default, any help is appreciated.

Comment: sync your project with gradle and let me know what error it shows in Event Log .

Comment: @pyus13 there is no error with syncing, the issue is that in my Java files, "import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;" it can find up to widget, but it can't find DrawerLayout to import.

Comment: Check the last part of answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316055/actionbaractivity-cannot-resolve-a-symbol