# Android Studio can't find compatibility library styles

Tags: android-studio

I'm relying on the compatibility library to use action bars on older versions of Android. I've added it to my `build.gradle` file like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}
```

And an example of a `styles.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Base theme -->
    <style name="AppName" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>
</resources>
```

The project builds successfully in Android Studio 0.4.4 both from the commandline and from the IDE. However, the following error appears when opening the file in the editor:

[image]

I've tried invalidating the cache, cleaning the project, syncing with Gradle and reimporting the project after deleting the IntelliJ files, but nothing changes. I also get errors like this in the `build.gradle` file:

[image]

But I don't know if that's related to this specific problem. How do I make Android Studio find the compatibility library resources?

Comment: It was an issue of 0.4.2, I am surprised to see such things in 0.4.4, Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316055/actionbaractivity-cannot-resolve-a-symbol/21316981#21316981

Comment: @pyus13 Strangely Android Studio *can* find the classes, it's only the resources it can't find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a bug in Android Studio, I have reported the bug here

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65979&thanks=65979&ts=1392399233

Follow this link for updates.

But one thing wondered me in your question is `@style` before `Theme.AppCompat.Light` @style is only used to refer your own styles.For appcompat styles I am directly using `Theme.AppCompat.Light` like

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

But error is showing as per your question in my case as well.

**For build.gradle file :**

As of now gradle file editor shows `"Cannot find symbols"` for all the things inside android tag. Not an issue.

Comment: Yeah, I added @style later in an attempt to fix it.