# android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity not resolve

Tags: android, adt

I just downloaded Android Developer Tools (ADT), which includes Eclipse, etc., and I followed Android's guide to create MyFirstApp. I've just spend over an hour looking for

```
android-support-v7-app.jar
```

but was unable to. Do you have any suggestions on how to handle the fact that for a blank template, ***android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity not resolve***.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: You can solve the problem at this page : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316055/actionbaractivity-cannot-resolve-a-symbol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you've downloaded the package android.support.v7. Then, Import the whole appcompat lib (/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat) as a library project to your workspace and then add to your main project as a library:

Here are the steps.

First check if android-support-v7-appcompat is already in your workspace. If it is go to Step 2

**Step 1:**

Select File > Import.

Select Existing Android Code Into Workspace and click Next.

Browse to the SDK installation directory and then to the Support Library folder.  /extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/.

Click Finish to import the project. For the v7 appcompat project, you should now see a new project titled android-support-v7-appcompat.

**Step 2:**

Right-click on your project -> Properties
In Android->Library section click Add
Select android-support-v7-appcompat -> Ok

Answer (score 44):

The use of `ActionBarActivity` **is now deprecated**, use

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
```

your class now must extends [**`AppCompatActivity`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html)

```
    public myClass extends AppCompatActivity{
...
...
```

if you have the message:

> cannot resolve symbol AppCompatActivity

You have to update to the last **[support library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)** in your `Android SDK Manager`

Comment: This is actually working answer. Please upvote it and move it to top.

Answer (score 4):

The use of `ActionBarActivity` and `v7` is outdated now and is no longer supported by latest versions of Android Studio.

To correct the error simply replace

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

with

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

and also replace the parent class `ActionBarActivity` with `AppCompatActivity`

For example: (old and not working): `public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity` with (new): `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`