# Cannot resolve symbols 'widget' and 'v7'. How do I fix this?

Tags: java, android

Android studio cannot resolve symbols `widget` and `v7`

I've tried :- restarting, importing, commenting the implementation statements and syncing it again, make sure libraries are up-to-date

```
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

Comment: Do you've support library in build.gradle file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your Android studio has migrated your project to androidx.
For further info check this link
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

> Use those instead if that's the case,

```
import androidx.cursoradapter.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

Comment: The SimpleCursorAdapter worked but the other one didn't. Do you know the import statement for ActionBarActivity?

Comment: The use of ActionBarActivity now is deprecated, so you need to use AppCompatActivity instead.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30383319/9210401