# Gradle Sync Failed after Adding Google Cloud Messaging Module

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an android app and I have a problem with Android Studio

I am using Android Studio and I wanted to add the GCM(Google Cloud Messaging) module, so I go to **app -> new module -> Google Cloud -> App Engine Backend with GCM**, then I click on Finish and Gradle starts synchronizing the project, but it says **"Gradle sync failed, basic functionality (compiling, debugging) will not work properly**, and in the MainActivity.java,  ActionBarActivity symbol cannot be resolved. I fixed the Activity error deleting the module, but I want to add it to my App.

P.S 1: 
**Specs**

- Android Studio v 1.2.1.1
- Widnows 7 Professional 64 bits
- Gradle:

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
```

Comment: So do you just want to add GCM to your app or do you want to build the backend as well?

Comment: I think both, I'm trying to make a messaging app where people can sign up. According to Google The backend template employs Google Cloud Endpoints to define a RESTful API which registers Android devices with your GCM server and allows you to send string messages to registered devices.

Answer (score 0):

If [ActionBarActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) cannot be found, it is probably because you do not have the Support Library installed. This is somewhat a duplicate question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316055/actionbaractivity-cannot-resolve-a-symbol).

Go to your SDK Manager on Android Studio and install Android Support Repository and Android Support Library.