# Android : can't resolve symbol ActionBarActivity

Tags: android

The compiler is not able to import the ActionBarActivity :

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

I tried to clean the project but it still shows the error , also i tried "Invalidate Caches/Restart" but didn’t solve the problem , finally i edit the build.grade file and change :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
```

to :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

but still shows the error .

I appreciate any help to solve this error.

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316055/actionbaractivity-cannot-resolve-a-symbol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActionBarActivity cannot resolve a symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316055/actionbaractivity-cannot-resolve-a-symbol)

Answer (score 7):

`ActionBarActivity` has been deprecated a long time ago and has probably been removed from the recent versions of the support library. Use `AppCompatActivity` instead.